# Android listFiles returns empty array

Tags: android

I uploaded several files to folder "/sdcard/Books/LadySusan" on my android emulator. When I check if file in folder exist, expression

```
new File("/sdcard/Books/LadySusan/ladysusan_1_austen_64kb.mp3").exists()
```

returns true, file exists in folder, but when I use

```
new File("/sdcard/Books/LadySusan").listFiles()
```

it returns empty array, not null but File[0]. I have permissions to read files from SD card

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and code to request them. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: First, **never hardcode paths**. There is no requirement for a device to have an `/sdcard` directory. Use methods on `Context` or `Environment`  to get root directories to use. Also note that you do not have access to arbitrary external storage locations on Android 10+ by default -- you need to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` on the `<application>` in the manifest.

Comment: I provided full path for simplicity. It is clear that SD card can be mounted to a different path. Regarding "android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" - it did not help, I added it to manifest, listFiles() still empty

Comment: I found an example [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-list-files-from-sd-card-with-runtime-permission-in-android) - it also does not work. It lists folders, but when I changed  
`File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/");`
to 
`File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Books/LadySusan");`
it did not return any files from folder

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug. As of Android 10, [external storage access is scoped to app files and media](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage).

This means that your application can only access the files in the app-specific directory (which can be retrieved in code with `getExternalFilesDir()`) or media in the media store.

As long as you target an Android version lower than API level 30 (Android 11) you can get away with accessing the external storage via the following permission:

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found. It seems to me there is a bug in Android SDK (10.0+). When I started emulator with Android 9.0, it returns files as I expected.

Comment: Can you point me to the bug in Android SDK 10+ please

Comment: I did not check if it exists as know bug, I just switched to another version where it worked. That is way I said "It seems to me...."

Comment: I don't think that it is a bug in the emulator.  In my app, I have .mp3 files in the /Music/ folder that listFiles() finds, but not the .zip file in the same folder.  It __seems to be__ a change in the permissions for SDK 30 that permits media files to be found, but not other types.